# How to send a successfull alert from Flask after uploading a file?

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I'm building a web application that uploads files and then sends them to two variables in order to make a vlookup - excel - using Pandas. My issue right now is the alert, and the page reloading, I need Flask to send the alert showing the upload is complete, but I don't know how to do that and preserve the two variables. All examples that I've found are not related to file upload or anything pertaining to Pandas. Please, how can I do it? Find my code below.

**Flask/Python**

```
import requests
from flask import request, Flask, render_template, make_response, flash
import pandas

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        dataframe_1 = pandas.read_excel(request.files.get('file_1'))
        dataframe_2 = pandas.read_excel(request.files.get('file_2'))
        
        
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="form">
   <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
         <div class="control-group" id="fields">
            <label class="control-label" for="formFile">
               Chis Ativo
            </label>
            <label class="control-label2" for="formFile2">
               Gis Mensal
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
               <div class="entry input-group
                  upload-input-group">
                  <input class="form-control"
                     name="file_1" type="file"
                     id="formFile" accept="xlsx" required>
                  
                  <input class="form-control"
                     name="file_2" type="file"
                     id="formFile2" accept="xlsx" required>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
               type="submit" value="Submit">Upload</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of form submit is that the page will be reloaded.

If you wish to prevent page reload, then you'll have to block the default form submit (intercept it) and submit the form via Javascript.

If you make it an Ajax (asynchronous) call, then your javascript code submits the form (which means no page reload), you receive the output from your server and do what you want with it

For sample code, Google - form submit via javascript without page reload

An example seems to be this [article](https://dev.to/filimonov/how-to-submit-an-html-form-without-reloading-the-page-2lgi)

Comment: That's perfect, it worked! But I have one problem: is not uploading my files anymore, do you have a clue?